# Can neutral density filters be substituted by other parameters of the imaging system in any context?

Tags: optics, photonics, imaging

One of illuminators in my imaging system has a built-in neutral density filter. I am considering removing it and changing the exposure time of the imaging system's camera to compensate for the increase in intensity after the filter is taken out.

This brings me to a more general question:

In what kind of contexts does a neutral density have no substitutes? By that I mean that other free parameters of the optical system (such as exposure time on camera or intensity adjustment of the light source) cannot be used to completely emulate its effect on the image.

Comment: Shutter time can be constrained by what you're trying to image. Sensor gain can generally be decreased, though in some cases, it night already be minimized -- after all, more gain is more noise. At least in photography, many "neutral" filters also actually cut UV, so that's another consideration

Comment: @AlexK By cutting UV, do you mean that it has a significant optical density in a range of wavelengths below a certain threshold?

Comment: Re: "intensity adjustment": many light sources, such as incandescent bulbs, change color as you change their intensity. Beware that you aren't just moving the neutral-density filter into your lamp here.

Comment: @ilykos -- yes -- at least the first few transmission spectra I found for "neutral density" filters had substantial UV attenuation

Answer (score 2):

Any shutter has a minimum time, below which it fails to function.

Some imaging systems are shutterless. The cameras on [TESS](https://tess.mit.edu/), for example, operate at a fixed exposure time of two seconds. They can't go faster because there is no shutter, and it takes two seconds to collect and digitize the pixels. And, of course, it has no control over the intensity of the sources (stars). The measurement chains cover the whole range from the noise floor to the blooming level, so adjusting the sensor gain is also useless.

Shrinking the aperture makes diffraction worse, so resolution suffers. And, of course, iris diaphragms have mechanical limits: while they can close completely, the accuracy of the aperture setting is poor for small apertures.